# Can't match tags using python xpath under lxml

Tags: python, xpath

Here's my code :

```
def extractContent(self,html):
    parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True)
    print html.find('id="detail"')
    tree = etree.fromstring(html,parser)
    if tree!=None:
      for c in self.contents:
        m = tree.xpath(c['xpath'])
        print m,c['xpath']
        if len(m) >= 1:
          print c['name'] + ' : ' + m[0].text
```

I am trying to match  **`//*[@id="i-detail"]/li[1]`**   in html source but it shows nothing.

here's the output of the code above:

```
25803
[] //*[@id="i-detail"]/li[1]
```

this is the html code:

```
<div class="mc fore tabcon">
                    <ul id="i-detail">
                        <li title="XXXXXXXXX">**AAAAAAAAAAA**(what i want to match)</li>
                        <li>BBBBBBBBB</li>
.......
```

I tried to use xpath under comandline:

```
>>> root.xpath('//*[@id="i-detail"]/li')
>>> []
>>> root.xpath('//*[@id="i-detail"]/*')
>>> [<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}li at 0x1007b7910>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}li at 0x1007b79b0>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}li at 0x1007b7a50>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}li at 0x1007b7aa0>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}li at 0x1007b7af0>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}li at 0x1007b7b40>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}li at 0x1007b7b90>]
>>> root.xpath('//*[@id="i-detail"]/*')[0] <----- this line could get the target !
```

Comment: Use `tree not is None`, `None` is a singleton.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working on my side:

```
>>> s = """<div class="mc fore tabcon">
                    <ul id="i-detail">
                        <li title="XXXXXXXXX">**AAAAAAAAAAA**(what i want to match)</li>
                        <li>BBBBBBBBB</li>
                    </ul>
</div>"""
>>> parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True)
>>> root = etree.fromstring(s, parser)
>>> for node in root.xpath('//*[@id="i-detail"]/li[1]'):
    print node, node.text


<Element li at 0x12534b8> **AAAAAAAAAAA**(what i want to match)
```